# How to display WiFi network (SSID) list on react native app using expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-wifi

Is there a way to display all Wifi list in react native using expo for Android. I have seen a few libraries but mostly for android and even those don't work properly. Any suggestions?

I want like :

[image]

Comment: I think it's not possible with Expo, it's  a feature not available now: check the answer in the forum: https://forums.expo.io/t/is-there-any-way-to-get-ssid-in-expo/1199/2

Answer (score 0):

use this [library](https://github.com/devstepbcn/react-native-android-wifi)
and this the code give you (SSID) list

```
getWifiNetworksOnPress(){
wifi.loadWifiList((wifiStringList) => {
    console.log(wifiStringList);
    var wifiArray = JSON.parse(wifiStringList);
   console.log(wifiArray);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

}

but in Android Api >25 you must be granted the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION (or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) permission in order to obtain results.

Answer (score 0):

Just visit [react-native-wifi-reborn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn).

**Usage**

```
import WifiManager from "react-native-wifi-reborn";

WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID(ssid, password, isWep).then(
   () => {
     console.log("Connected successfully!");
   },
   () => {
     console.log("Connection failed!");
   }
 );

 WifiManager.getCurrentWifiSSID().then(
   ssid => {
     console.log("Your current connected wifi SSID is " + ssid);
   },
   () => {
     console.log("Cannot get current SSID!");
   }
 );
```

I hope it will work.